# Step by step guide on installing leksah on mac for haskell compilation?

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, haskell-platform, leksah

Can anyone provide steps on installing leksah on mac to compile haskell? The documents are not helpful. These are the steps provided: a binary installer for your operating system, which is typically Windows or Macintosh.
a package for your platform, which is currently Arch Linux and Fedora Linux, and Debian(Ubuntu) is in preparation.
install from sources from Hackage via cabal install leksah
leksah or leksah-head development repositories. (If you want the very last or want to help with Leksah development).
But my terminal constantly shows errors if I do these.

Comment: What errors [edit] your post to include the full [formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) (as in put (```) around) error message. What sort of Mac (specifically Intel based or Apple silicone that matters for "binary installer"s). With the little info you've provided it's hard to help.

Comment: A word of warning: when I last tried Leksah it was still pretty far from smoothly usable, and it doesn't seem to have been much developed/maintained since. Most Haskell programmers use other, non-Haskell-specific IDEs / editors, either with [Haskell Language Server](https://haskell-language-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) integration or just as plain text editors.

Comment: *Don't* put crucial information in the comments, instead [edit] your post to include them.

Comment: You can use brew to install it, with some caveats: https://github.com/leksah/leksah/issues/531 But I recommend just using Haskell language Server with e.g. VSCode (using [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=haskell.haskell))